# Tikz remember picture on wrong page

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, tikzmark

I want to comment some equations with `tikz` and stumbled upon a `tikzmark` command that uses the `remember picture` command. It works fine, I can draw below and above the equation, but whenever the equation is too close to the end of the page, the "annotation" is printed on the next page. How can I avoid this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,bending}
\newcommand{\tikzmmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=base] \node (#1) {\ensuremath{#2}};}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
    \vspace{0.7cm}
\end{equation}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
    \draw (mb) ++(0,-0.3) |- ++( 1.0,-0.4) node[right] {second};
\end{tikzpicture}%
End of paragraph text.

\lipsum[2]
\vspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
\end{equation}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
    \draw (mb) ++(0,+0.3) |- ++( 1.0,+0.4) node[right] {second};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]
\vspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
\end{equation}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
    \draw (mb) ++(0,+0.3) |- ++( 1.0,+0.4) node[right] {second};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

which results in: 
[image: Annotation for eq. 3 on wrong page]

Comment: Put the drawing command within the `equation` environment

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Is there a short explanation, why the tikz node/coordinate is not absolute and hence preserved over page breaks?

Comment: after the equation environment TeX decides that *OK I'm done with this environment the page is already full*. Stops reading the rest until that page is shipped out. But the coordinates of the tikz marks are written to the aux file as the **current page coords**. Then TeX comes back to the parsing and sees that there are some TikZ stuff referring to the current page but because now we are in the new page TeX puts them at the bottom of the page since it is the new **current page**

Comment: I wasn't aware of the current page coords procedure. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I am answering the question myself, but credit goes to [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse), who posted the solution in the comments above (4 weeks ago).

The drawing commands have to be put inside the `equation` environment, e.g.

```
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
                \draw (mb) ++(0,+0.3) |- ++( 1.0,+0.4) node[right] {second};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{equation}%
```

in order to make sure, that the drawing command is not executed on the next page.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,bending}
\newcommand{\tikzmmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=base] \node (#1) {\ensuremath{#2}};}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
    \vspace{0.7cm}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
                \draw (mb) ++(0,-0.3) |- ++( 1.0,-0.4) node[right] {second};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{equation}%
End of paragraph text.

\lipsum[2]
\vspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
                \draw (mb) ++(0,+0.3) |- ++( 1.0,+0.4) node[right] {second};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{equation}%
\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]
\vspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{equation}
    J = \tikzmmark{mb}{J_2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\small]%
                \draw (mb) ++(0,+0.3) |- ++( 1.0,+0.4) node[right] {second};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{equation}%
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've experienced a similar issue where, however, the environment containing the `\tikzmark` is itself so long that is spans multiple pages (a `verse` env), with the `\tikzmark` being toward the beginning, and anyway typeset in the first of the pages where `verse` is layed out; in that situation it's certainly necessary to put the `tikzpicture` inside `verse`, but it's not sufficient. One has to literally move it to right after the `\tikzmark`.